# How to only search the current working directory not subdirectories with glob

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob

I tried to use glob to acquire all of the .txt files in the current working directory, but unfortunately, it acquired all of the .txt files in the cwd and all .txt files in subdirectories of the cwd. How can I get glob to only collect the .txt files in the cwd?

Comment: You need to show some code. It seems you are using "recursive = True" if I am not mistaken.

Comment: This is correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you can fix it with a for loop.

```
#root= root of file
#filenames= all files
#directories= all folders

for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(directory):
print(root)
print(filenames)
```